# При добавлении товара в всплывающей корзине не работают + и -

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема:  Если добавляю в корзину 2 и более товара то + и - перестают работать у всех товаров кроме самого последнего. Они как бы добавляются, потом обновляются товары  и количество остается прежним, вот пример:

Сразу добавляю в корзину 1 позицию одного товара, потом еще добавляю 2 позиции второго товара.
Перехожу в корзину, и тот товар что был первый с 1 позицией, я хочу увеличить на 1 позицию, нажимаю +, показывается уже 2, происходит обновление и снова становится 1. Но если хочу добавить позицию ко второму товару(последнему, сейчас там 2 позиции), нажимаю +, становится 3 позиции, происходит обновление и остается 3 позиции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ищи проблему в своих теме-плагинах. Из коробки всё работает как надо.

Comment: Дело в том, что без результатов что выводятся у тебя в консоли, ничего сказать  мы не можем. Скорее всего у тебя конфликт скриптов или скрипт ожидает библиотеку, которая ещё не подргузилась. Нужна отладка именно твоего набора плагинов, а этим заниматься мало кто готов (бесплатно). Посмотри что в консоли. Есть ли ошибки или нет, и какие. За одно посмотри остатки товара, может у тебя остаток 3шт.